# How to get DateTime.Now() in YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD format using C#

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [datetime to string with time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323113/datetime-to-string-with-time-zone)

This is one of the W3C standard date time format that I want to use in sitemap. This DateTime standard is:

> Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
>         YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD where TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm) (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)

I am using the following code to get the current DateTime in that format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssTZD");
```

But this gives: 2011-08-10T02:27:20TZD

Apparently the DateTime.Now doesn't recognize "TZD" in the parameter. Please help. How can I get the current DateTime in this format?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` never even sees that parameter. It's a parameter to the `ToString` method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the `zzz` format specifier to get the timezone offset as hours and minutes. You also want to use the `HH` format specifier to get the hours in 24 hour format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

Result:

```
2011-08-09T23:49:58+02:00
```

Some culture settings uses periods instead of colons for time, so you might want to use literal colons instead of time separators:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH':'mm':'sszzz")
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: how is it possible you have got 24h mod and me 12h mode?

Comment: Plus one for mentioning literal colons; people tend to forget that `:` represents the time separator of the current format provider.

Comment: Passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is one way to ensure that the `:` is not translated.  Also it ensures the Gregorian calendar is used - as it's also possible the current culture's calendar is something else.

Comment: @genesis the capital letters "HH" shows the 24 hour format while the small letters "hh" shows the 12 hour format.

Answer (score 10):

use zzz instead of TZD

Example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz");
```

Response:

```
2011-08-09T11:50:00:02+02:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz");
```

`zzz` is the timezone offset.

Comment: is there a way to add milliseconds as well?

Comment: Oh yeah! I found it..:  
fff - is for fraction of second.
  
`code` DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:fffzzz");