# Date conversion

Tags: c#

I need help to convert current date to "Tue Nov 4 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014" date format
using C#.

Say I have date like : `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;`

Now, how can I convert it in mentioned format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323113/datetime-to-string-with-time-zone

Comment: Do you mean you have a value `dt` and you want to ***format*** it in a specific way. Use `.ToString(" ... ")`.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: yes, I have the value in dt and want to convert it in that specific format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based upon your suggestions, I build this code

```
DateTimeOffset localTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
string.Format("{0:ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss} UTC+{1} {0:yyyy}", localTime, localTime.Offset.ToString("hhmm"));
```

and its generating correct format:
"Tue Nov 4 18:25:48 UTC+0530 2014"

Comment: @HamidP: r u sure that if change "hhmm" to "HHmm" is going to work. Have u tested it?If I change "hhmm" to "HHmm" then I am getting System.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to specify a format for your date. You can construct a custom format using [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like taking risk to answer your question but anyway..

A `DateTime` doesn't have `any` implicit format. It just have date and time values etc.. That's why it is not possible to have any format. But `string` representations of them can have a format. Formatting a `DateTime` is easy, just need to use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with a specific culture. (In your case looks like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good candidate)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC+0530' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

returns

```
Tue Nov 4 14:20:36 UTC+0530 2014
```

*AFAIK*, time zone abbreviations are not standardized and that's why there is way to parse them besides literal string delimiter. Also since a `DateTime` doesn't keep [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value, you need also parse it as a literal string delimiter

If you would want to `+05:30` instead `+0530` as a result, [`"zzz"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) would be a nice choice since it gets `+` or `-` sign, hours and minutes part offset of local operating system's time zone from `UTC`.

Comment: If you use `"ddd MMM d HH':'mm':'ss 'UTC+0530' yyyy"` with the colons `:` protected by single quotes, it is not necessary to specify the format provider (culture info), I think.

Comment: Note that `"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'UTC'zzz yyyy"` will reflect the time zone of the current machine (the `zzz` part) but there will be a colon between `05` and `30` (assuming Indian/Sri Lankan locale).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes but if OP's `CurrentCulture` is different than english based culture, `ddd` and `MMM` might generates different abbreviated names as results than `Tue` and `Nov`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are right about `zzz` format and missing `:` between `05` and `30` (will add to my answer as well). That's why I couldn't find any solution (even if there is another way, I don't know) except literal string delimiter.