# Timestamp YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.0000000-00:00 Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, datetime-format

I am using C#.net and Asp.net. I am trying to get the following format and assign that value into a TextBox. I am not sure how to accomplish. It has to be in this timestamp format:  "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.0000000-00:00"

Comment: What do you mean by "get the following format"? It's very unclear what information you've already got, what you need, and what you've tried...

Comment: this question should help you figure out what you need.  Scroll through all the answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format

Comment: I have tryied using "DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;"  Then I tried using the datetime.tostring method but getting the right outcome.

Comment: Adam Heeg thanks this will help me

Comment: It looks like the end -00:00 may be the difference from UTC and may need to be appended to the first part as a second string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datetime to string with time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323113/datetime-to-string-with-time-zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("o") + DateTime.Now.ToString("zzz");
```