# How can I format a DateTimeOffset to not have a colon in the timezone offset?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I was reading this MSDocs article about DateTime-related format support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support#support-for-the-iso-8601-12019-format

And I was trying to cast datetime to string with this format **without colon in the timezone part**:

> 2021-01-01T14:30:10+0030

I want to cast this datetimeoffset to string. I use this format:

> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz

But the output of the ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz") method is:

> 2021-01-01T14:30:10+00:30

It has **colon** (:) sign in timezone part.
How can I cast it like '2021-01-01T14:30:10+0030'? (without colon in the timezone part)

Can I format the timezone part?

Comment: So the problem is the space character?

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280746/10197418)?

Comment: `string result = $"{date:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszz}{date.Offset:mm}";`

Comment: You cannot offset the timezone part.

Comment: To me, this looks a lot like the [datetime roundtrip format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) - i.e. the 'O' format specifier.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://www.ideone.com/RifLYJ

Comment: as @DmitryBychenko said https://dotnetfiddle.net/BRuBim

Comment: @MrFuppes yes but I don't want to use Remove method

Comment: @PMF no, the problem is the colon in timezone part

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  the 'O' format specifier shows datetimeoffset timezone part with the colon. I want to show datetimeoffset without colon sign in the timezone part

Comment: You can't. Remove it afterwards.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That is the correct answer... post it as an answer!

Comment: @Ian Kemp: A clumsy solution it is - that's why I've put it as a comment - glueing together two formatted values (date + minutes). However since there are no better code provide, let it be an answer

Comment: Keep in mind that the format you're asking for is *not* compliant with the ISO 8601 standard.  The standard allows either the "basic" format (without delimiters) for the entire string, or the "extended" format (with delimiters) for the entire string.  It does not allow for a mixture of the basic and extended formats within the same string.  You are using the extended format for the date and time portions, with the basic format for the offset portion, which is prohibited by the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's not possible (in .Net 6 at least) to get a *format string* for `DateTimeOffset` to get the required representation. However, you can try *combining* two formats: `date` (which is of type`DateTimeOffset`) and ints `Offset` (of type `TimeSpan`)

```
string result = $"{date:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszz}{date.Offset:mm}";
```

Here we combine

1. `date:date:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszz` - `date` with Offset up to *hours*
2. `date.Offset:mm` - `Offset` minutes